# How to make a for loop with cor.test faster in R?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, matrix, memory

I have the following code with example data. My real data are very large, so I would like to make the code as fast as possible.

I only care about making the `for` loop (between the `#######` lines) faster, the rest is no problem.

I already made it faster by removing `data.frame`, then removing `data.table`, `cbind()` and finally using only `matrix` and `list`. This improved speed of the loop **a lot**, but only on small data. With my large data, it is still very slow.

I suspect this is because the growing `list()` is somehow copied in each iteration of the `for` loop? Maybe `cor.test` is also slow?

I read here (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html#t-test) that maybe changing the `cor.test` function could speed things up?

How can I make this `for` loop memory efficient and as fast as possible? Thank you.

```
 mtcars <- as.matrix(mtcars)
 mtcars.1 <- mtcars[4:30,1:5]
 mtcars.2 <- mtcars[1:20,6:10]
 mtcars_merge <- merge(x = mtcars.1, y = mtcars.2, by="row.names", all = TRUE)
 rownames(mtcars_merge) <- mtcars_merge[,1]
 mtcars_merge[,1] <- NULL
 mtcars_merge <- as.matrix(mtcars_merge)
 col.names.m1 <- colnames(mtcars.1)
 col.names.m2 <- colnames(mtcars.2)
 my_list = list()
 ###########################################
 for (col1 in col.names.m1) {
   for (col2 in col.names.m2) {
     x <- mtcars_merge[, col1]
     y <- mtcars_merge[, col2]
     if (sum(complete.cases(cbind(x, y))) > 3) {
       result <- cor.test(x, y, method = "pearson")
     my_list[[paste0(col1, "_", col2)]] <- c(col1, col2, result$estimate, result$p.value, sum(complete.cases(cbind(x, y))))
     }
   }
 }
 ###########################################
 my_list2 <- do.call(rbind, my_list)
 df <- as.data.frame(my_list2)
 row.names(df) <- NULL
 colnames(df) <- c('col1_name', 'col2_name', 'Pearson.r', 'p.value', 'n (complete.cases)')
 df
```

Comment: The major gains achieved in that article were due to negating the calculation of p-values and the `print()` prep. If you want p-values etc. in your output, any modification to `cor.test()` may be trivial. [This link](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/cor.test.R) has the source code for the `cor.test()` function. If you are only using "pearson" and you know x and y are always the same length *and* numeric, there's quite a bit of code you could strip out. However, I am guessing that removing some of the `if()` from `cor.test()` won't result in major gains.

Comment: If you do choose to modify `cor.test()` be great if you posted the result. I'm curious to see how it would affect output times.

Comment: Thank you for the ```cor.test()``` source code. Modifying it is scary but I can try. I personally thought there might be a more efficient way to code the ```my_list[[``` ... part, but I am not sure how. What do you think?

Comment: How large is your very large data? Different strategies sometimes make more sense depending on the scale and shape of the data.

Comment: I can't help with the efficiency of your `my_list[[` sorry. As I mentioned, it's likely making a modified version of `cor.test()` won't result in major gains but that code isn't as scary as it looks. Once you've copied it into an R script, RStudio helpfully highlights pairs of brackets and braces. You can follow the breadcrumbs as it were to see where each unneeded part starts and ends.

Comment: But before you go down the modified `cor.test()` route, respond to @JonSpring and anyone else as there is likely a much faster solution. Rest assured that if there are efficiencies to be gained, someone on SO will give you a solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, @JonSpring .  Matrix 1 (equivalent to mtcars.1) = 1406 x 18,000. Matrix 2 (equivalent to mtcars.2) = 919 x 7,000. Thank you.

Comment: You have calculated `sum(complete.cases(cbind(x, y))) > 3` twice inside the loop. You have made at least two unnecessary copies of columns with `mtcars_merge`. I'll post an answer that implements corrections on these two points.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to avoid some unnecessary calculations or copying of data objects. Also removed the unnecessary `cbind`, since `complete.cases` will accept either data.frames or matrix arguments.

```
 for (col1 in col.names.m1) {
   for (col2 in col.names.m2) {
     # x <- mtcars_merge[, col1] .... not needed
     # y <- mtcars_merge[, col2]
     if ( ss <- sum(complete.cases(mtcars_merge[, c(col1, col2) ])) > 3) {
       result <- cor.test(mtcars_merge[, col1], mtcars_merge[, col2], method = "pearson")
       my_list[[paste0(col1, "_", col2)]] <- 
                    c(col1, col2, result$estimate, result$p.value, ss)
     }
   }
 }
```

The speed gain with that test case was modest. <strike>I would also point out that you are effectively doing each test twice since `cor(a,b)` should equal `cor(b,a)`. You might gain 50% by constructing the loop indices to avoid duplication.</strike> Also there are functions in packages such as that of Harrell's Hmisc's `rcorr` that will return p-values and correlation coefficients for pairwise selection of an n-column matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll test how much faster this for loop is :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @IRTFM. I like your answer and suggestions and am still testing speed gain on a fraction of my data. I would like to point out that I am not duplicating correlations, because I will only get correlations between all ```mtcars.1``` columns and all ```mtcars.2``` columns  :)

Comment: Thanks again @IRTFM. I tested your suggestion on part of my data. The previous code took 3 hours, 16 minutes (average of two tests). This code took 3 hours, 51 minutes (average of two tests), so it turned out to be 18% slower. Your suggestion looked better to me, but in practice it was a little slower. I do not have deep enough understanding to explain why that would be, but thank you again for your answer! :)